# How to include all Vim config files in some folder?

Tags: vim, file-management, vimrc

I want to reorganization my `vim` directory to be like this:

```
- dotfiles
  |- vim
  |  |- config
  |  |  |- global
  |  |  |  |- basic.vim
  |  |  |  |...
  |  |  |- plugins
  |  |  |  |- ctrl-p.vim
  |  |  |  |...
  |  |  |- functions
  |  |  |  |...
  |  |  |...
  |  |- bootstrap.vimrc
```

in `$HOME/.vimrc`:

```
if isdirectory(expand('$HOME/dotfiles/vim'))
  source $HOME/dotfiles/vim/bootstrap.vimrc
endif
```

My question is, how to include all Vim config files in `global`, `plugins`, `functions` folder?

I find a function like this:

```
function! SourceConfig()
  let file_list = split(globpath('$HOME/dotfiles/vim/', '.vim'), '\n')

  for file in file_list
    execute('source '.file)
  endfor
endfunction

call sourceConfig()
```

But I want to according to the specified load folder, how to modify the func, make the `globpath` change to be an `array` or something, like below.

```
let $path=[global, plugins, functions] // this will be source files in turn.

function! SourceConfig()
  let file_list = split(globpath($path, '.vim'), '\n')

  for file in file_list
    execute('source '.file)
  endfor
endfunction

call sourceConfig()
```

Use before/plugin and after/plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `globpath()` takes a comma-separated list of directories, you can build the locations like this (I'm doing this in a primitive way with duplication, as you seem to be not very well versed in Vimscript):

```
function! sourceConfig()
  let path = $HOME  . '/dotfiles/vim/config/global'
  let path .= ',' . $HOME  . '/dotfiles/vim/config/plugins'
  let path .= ',' . $HOME  . '/dotfiles/vim/config/functions'
```

Then, this list can be passed to generate the list of script files, which can then be sourced (note that your syntax was wrong, and it's recommended to do proper escaping):

```
  let file_list = split(globpath(path, '*.vim'), '\n')

  for file in file_list
    execute 'source' fnameescape(file)
  endfor
endfunction
```

#### Critique of approach

You didn't mention the motivation for that reorganization, but I would **recommend to stick to default configuration layouts**, either the "all under .vim" or the "separate bundle directories per plugin".

For example, your listed approach doesn't handle *ftplugins* or *autoload*, which I'm sure some of your plugins has / will have.